# Position label text on conditional basis

Tags: jfreechart

[image]

In the above bar chart, for the grey bar I want the label text (Threshold 50%) to be displayed inside the grey bar. Currently its showing outside because of the below code

```
renderer.setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.red);
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(
                    ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT,
                    TextAnchor.CENTER, 0.0));
```

How to I apply the above condition only to the 2nd red bar & not to other bars

Here is my dataset

```
cat Category       Value
0                  0.000000
1   You 10%        0.100000
2   Threshold 50%  0.500000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved by overriding `getPositiveItemLabelPosition` method of `AbstractCategoryItemRenderer` java class.

```
@Override
    public ItemLabelPosition getPositiveItemLabelPosition(int row,
            int column) {
        CategoryDataset dataset = getPlot().getDataset();
        double value = dataset.getValue(row, column).doubleValue();
        if (value < 0.15) {
            return new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3,
                    TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, TextAnchor.CENTER, 0.0);
        } else {
            return new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE3,
                    TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT, TextAnchor.CENTER, 0.0);
        }

    }
```